# i want to remove the sign up flow from hosted ui but wish to keep it in my application where I am using the SDK. how can i do it

Tags: amazon-cognito, amazon-cognito-triggers

I am using AWS Cognito I want to remove the signup flow from hosted UI as I wish to do some application-level stuff during signup.(I can't do such stuff in pre-signup lambda). I tried changing the policy as advised by other links, but that causes trouble for the creating users through sdk (error : Users cant be created in this userpool).

Note: I can use AdminCreateUser function in the SDK but that changes my Userflow.

Please advice how to remove signup link from Hosted UI but allow it using SDK

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup two different App Clients. In the console, there is a section called App Client Settings, at the top of the App Client Settings you will have Identity Providers you have configured, like Google, Facebook and Cognito User Pool.

At the moment you probably have one app client with all Identity Providers selected. In the hosted UI url, there is a parameter called `client_id`. Similarly in your SDK you specify a clientid to connect to.

You can setup two independent App Clients, with different identity providers and different client Ids. In you hosted UI client you can disable 'Cognito User Pool'.